# Thread.sleep() Not Working Sometimes

Tags: java

Apologies for the bad title. I am working on a game that uses a JTextPane as the main text view. I use the following code to print to the pane:

```
public void write(String txt, MessageType t) {
        try {
            for (char c : txt.toCharArray()) {
                text.getDocument().insertString(text.getDocument().getLength(), String.valueOf(c), t.getAttributes());
                Utils.pause(30);
            }
            text.getDocument().insertString(text.getDocument().getLength(), "\n", t.getAttributes());
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

That code writes each character one at a time, sleeping for 30 milliseconds between each writing. It then writes a new line character. Here's the pause() method if you're interested:

```
public static void pause(int millis) {
        try { Thread.sleep(millis); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

Most of the time, this works fine. It writes each character with some space in between, giving the impression of typing. However, there is one instance where it does not work.

I have a JTextField that handles input. I added this KeyListener to it:

```
input.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    CommandParser.getInstance().parse(input.getText());
                    input.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
```

At the end of the parse() method of CommandParser, if a command isn't found, this line runs:

```
Game.getInstance().getGUI().write("Invalid command.", GUI.MessageType.BAD);
```

However, for that line only, the program waits a second, then prints everything at once, instead of printing one character every 30 milliseconds. Why is this? Does this have to do with inner classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your action is happening on the EDT thread. The GUI will not update at all until you return from that method. You need to use something like `SwingWorker` or `SwingTimer` to farm the updates out to another thread.

Comment: Thought so; let me try.

Comment: Hm, then I've got to ask: why wouldn't you try before posting to SO?

Comment: I thought it might have had to do with threading, but I needed some specifics.

Comment: Tim, I tried using a `Thread`, `Timer`, and `SwingWorker`, but multiple texts write themselves at the same time which results in jumble. I tried the `synchronized` keyword, but to no avail.

Comment: Just use the swingworker, and each time it calls back just write the next character. Only ever have one running at a time and as more texts go in just add them to the end of the text its writing.

Comment: Two things: First, how exactly would I have one writer that keeps getting called? Second, each time I want to write a `String`, I also want a `MessageType`, which contains a `SimpleAttributeSet` that will be used it `insertString()`.

Comment: Just keep a reference to the writer and have a collection of messages to send stored inside it. Call a method to add a message in it, have it constantly process any messages that are waiting

Comment: How do I make the `SwingWorker` keep running? Recursion? A method inside `SwingWorker`?

Comment: I've not actually used SwingWorker much so can't be more specific you are going to need to read up on threads. Particularly waiting on objects, notifying, etc... and synchronization too maybe. Most likely you just need to wait on the list of messages, and then be notified when a new one is added.

Comment: Figured out a temporary solution: Make a new `Thread` inside of the `ActionListener`. Since the `write()` method now disables the input field and reenables it after writing, this works fine. I know it's not the best idea, but it works for now.